# JPA: One entity mapped to multiple rows, is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

In JPA, can I map an Entity to a table where attributes of the entity are persisted across multiple rows?

Basically, can I map a class like this:

```
public Document {
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String size;
}
```

To a table like

```
CREATE TABLE DOC_METADATA
(
    DOC_ID NUMBER,
    ATTR_NAME VARCHAR,
    ATTR_VALUE VARCHAR
);
```

With content like

```
DOC_ID   | ATTR_NAME     | ATTR_VALUE
1          "title"         "Alice in wonderland"
1          "author"        "Lewis Carroll"
1          "size"          "500kb"
2          "title"         "Winnie the pooh"
2          "author"        "A. A. Milne"
2          "size"          "600kb"
```

Comment: This wil work. When you query all data from your table you will have one instance of your entity for each row of you table.

Comment: If i run  Document doc = em.find(Document.class, "1"); what will be in the doc?

Comment: they aren't persisted across multiple rows ... you have two Entities per row. And NO you can't do that

Comment: I know it wouldn't be standard or best practice but at least you probably would be able to map individual fields from that table as OneToOne relationships? Something like OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinTable(name="DOC_METADATA" joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DOC_ID", referencedColumnName="ATTR_NAME")) basically map a String as you would map a normal entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's impossible. Your **class Document** is a domain class (java presentation of your table in db). When you try to create table from domain class so  will be created a table with such fields like in your domain class.

Comment: What would you do if you had a legacy database and had to read/write to a table like above?

Comment: You should add domain class with such fields like in database and after that you can manipulate with this table. For example for table with fields DOC_ID   | ATTR_NAME     | ATTR_VALUE - you create class like this: public class DomainClass { private Long id; private String name; private String value; getters and setters}. It will be your domain class for work with your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take look at what JPA is. Take a look at

- http://www.programming-simplified.com/jpa_video_training.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro.htm#BNBPZ